# Is it possible to somehow hide or override the arrow in the top left hand corner when opening android system settings (e.g. ACTION_SOUND_SETTINGS)?

Tags: android, kotlin, settings, back

Really tried my best finding the answer all around the internet. But failed.

I have an app in kotlin. From a fragment I am opening system settings to set up the sound.

```
 buttonSound = root.findViewById(R.id.btnZvuk)
        buttonSound.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(Settings.ACTION_SOUND_SETTINGS)
            startActivity(intent)
```

When the screen appears in newer android version there is an arrow in the top left hand corner which leads to android system settings. I need to prevent this behavior. But I am not able to find a way how.

I tried to override onBackPressed(), some Intent flags, onOptionsItemSelected() but nothing worked. Do you have any suggestions please? I am desperate.

Thank you in advance. Looking forward for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

> When the screen appears in newer android version there is an arrow in the top left hand corner which leads to android system settings

There are tens of thousands of Android device models. The exact UI of the Settings app will vary, as the Settings app usually is customized by device manufacturers. This is not strictly tied to the Android OS version.

> I need to prevent this behavior

That is not an option in general, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this can be done by  directly kotlin but these kind of things can be usually handle with work on AOSP with that we can customize the behavior of Android OS.